# Showing template parameters for function in a class diagram

Tags: uml

How should I show on the class diagram that fnc of this class uses some extra params not listed in the class declaration?
For example:

```
template<class SomePolicy>
struct SomeClass
{
template<class T>//<= here fnc uses param type not listed in class decl.
void f();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring the `template<class T>` return argument? If so, usually I create a new type, in this case for the `template<class T>`.

My main experience is only with ArgoUML and that's the only way I've found to do that with ArgoUML. It's not beautiful, but it works :)

You can also try to create a new class with the template type and the set it as return type for your class. You can find an example with Visual Paradigm here: http://oldresources.visual-paradigm.com/uml_diagrams/class_diagram/drawing_class_with_template_parameter.html

Comment: what do you mean by "return type for my class"?

Comment: @There: sorry, return type for your **method**. My bad... xD

Comment: what I would like to know, is, how to show on class diagram that fnc f has additional template params to those of its class

Comment: Each operation has own specification, so you can set Template Parameters in Operation Specification dialog. If you want to show them in diagram, you need to enable in Presentation Option under operations submenu